# Windows 7 manage accounts

Tags: windows, command-line, user-accounts, administrator

I have two different computers running windows 7 ultimate.
Each computer has its own user accounts (both Administrators on the local computer).

I try to figure how can I give an administrator permission on one computer to user located on the other or manage the other computer by using its administrator account \ sending cmd command over the net which will have the right (top) permission to work.

Answer (score 3):

The way you do it is create an account on the other computer, with the same username and password.

In "stand-alone" Windows systems, all accounts are completely local. When you connect from computer A to computer B, you must have an account on B, and that account's privileges will be applied. The account type on computer A does not matter – in fact, even the "same username" is merely for convenience, not a requirement at all. (If they are different, you will simply be asked to enter the password when connecting.)

Remember though, that if computer B has UAC enabled (which it should), Administrator rights will be "filtered out" when connecting over the network. Read [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28WS.10%29.aspx) on how to obtain full Administrator privileges.